# TWIG templates system basic and simple installation?

Tags: php, templates, twig

trying to use TWIG templates system on my php project , its my first time i am using this templates system , when i went to [installation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/installation.html) page i found to many ways

also is it require apache extension to work ? becouse i found this in the bottom of the page

```
extension=twig.so #For Unix systems
extension=php_twig.dll #For Windows systems
```

i am developing my script on my Mac , i could't find example for Mac

if someone using this templates system can you advice me how to basically install this script ?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found it

1. copy the folder "lib" to your project

and this is example code

```
require_once("/path here/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php" );

  Twig_Autoloader::register();

  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem( DIR . '/templates/');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => DIR . '/cache',
));

echo $twig->render('home.tpl', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

Comment: Also: no, the PHP extension is not needed to work, it's designed for sites with heavy load.